# GIT merge omits commits in other branches

Tags: eclipse, git, merge, egit

I have the following repository structure

```
branch master    : for final stable tag releases
branch develop   : for ongoing developement and combination of features
branch team      : A branch for another developing team
branch feat/foo  : A feature developed by the oter developing team
```

I want to achieve the following flow:

```
master    ------------------*
                           /
develop   -----*--*---*---* (final bugfix, merge with 'master' for final stable tag)
                     /
team      --*---*---*  (summarized team developement merged into 'develop')
                   /
feat/foo  --*--*--*  (finalized feature merged into B)
```

I see that the team merged the feature ('feat/foo') into their team branch ('team'). I then merged the 'team' branch into my 'develop' branch, but somehow I am missing some of their commits (e868d17 and 0091ed2). I tried to merge also feat/foo separately, but you see the outcome in the picture below...

Any idea how I can properly merge the branches to develop? And why does the merge omit these two commits?

I am using Eclipse to do the GIT handling. It does not flag any conflicts during the merge.

[image: Bit Bucket Repository]

Comment: Are you missing _commits_ or are you missing actual functionality in your branch which should have been done by other developers?  When you merge one branch in Git to another branch typically the changes come into the target branch as a merge commit, with two parent branches.  I am fairly certain that the commits you may have in mind are there in the history, but perhaps you can't find it.

Comment: Well I see in the details of the commit (e.g. 0091ed2) what changes have been made and the file version was increased, but in my head, after doing the merge, I do not see these changes and an older version. So I am really MISSING the actual commit and the commit is not listed in the file history in eGit either...

Comment: Redoing a merge with 'team' and a 'push to branch develop' afterwards says 'up to date'. The screenshot also shows that my merge is newer than those commits, but they are just not included during the merge...!?

Comment: You did not answer my question, and you are confused about what a commit represents.  Are you missing any functionality?

Comment: As I said, I am missing updates (functionality) in a file I have in 'develop' branch after the merge, which was updated in 'feat/foo' branch, is that what you mean?

Comment: Then maybe someone botched the merge, or the merge did not happen.  Did you pull the branch first?

Comment: I pulled 'develop', pushed 'develop', merged 'team', pushed 'develop'

Comment: Have you pulled 'team', though? Because if you didn't, you merged with the old local copy of that branch, possibly omitting the commits added by someone else.

Comment: I do not have this branch locally, I only have 'develop' on my machine

Comment: Do a `git fetch` to get all branches locally.  Work backwards from `develop` until you find the missing code (i.e. go to the parent branches in reverse order).  Maybe you colleagues did not commit something.

Comment: I just found the issues, I switched to GIT repository view and did synchronisation. Then the most recent commits on 'team' were available for merging. I did no have to do this earlier though, I am very confused. But now all branches are merged...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to manually synchronize the repository.
Right click on project > Team > Synchronize Workspace
or synrchonize in GIT View